# RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=3$.How to work only page=3？ I do not want to redirect page=33

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**I want to redirect only `/?page=3` to `/`.**

`/?page=33` is not redirect.

---

**The following code also redirects `/?page=33`**

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=3$
  RewriteRule / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Will `page=3` always be the *only* parameter in the query? Never any analytics or session parameters? If not, your accepted answer will not work consistently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=3$
RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L]
```

With `?` to prevent the automatic addition of `?page=3`

Comment: Thanks. I could redirected.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this, clear your browser cache first after that if it works change `R=302` to `301`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=3
RewriteRule ^ / [R=302,L]
```